# Mixed transports in NServiceBus 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, nservicebus

I'm currently working on a project that combines Java and .NET systems. The communication between the two is from Java over ActiveMQ to .NET MSMQ using BizTalk as a translator.

I was wondering if we could cut out BizTalk when using NServiceBus 4.0 and use 2 different transport types in 1 NServiceBus instance. Incoming events should be picked up from ActiveMQ and published using MSMQ.

The NServiceBus instance in this case is self-hosted within a WCF service on IIS and injected into the business logic using a Unity container.

Is this going to be possible or do I need to stick to 1 transport type per instance/host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved the issue by using a satellite in NServiceBus that uses Apache.NMS and Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ to consume an existing ActiveMQ queue and create a new message that we put on the bus. Using NServiceBus 4.0 default MSMQ transport and not mixing transports to consume the non-NServiceBus managed ActiveMQ.

Answer (score 2):

With version 4.0 of NServiceBus, you can use ActiveMQ on both sides cutting out both BizTalk and MSMQ.

UPDATE:

You could have a regular NSB endpoint listening to ActiveMQ and have it call Bus.SendToSites where you configure the message to go out over MSMQ to your regular endpoints.

Comment: Cutting out MSMQ is not really an option right now, I'm looking into the possibility to monitor an ActiveMQ queue from c# and publish the messages from that queue on the bus.

Comment: In this case I have existing Java-created messages that are put on a queue I'd like to consume using an ActiveMQ endpoint config without the Java side having any knowledge of the NServiceBus queue consumption. I only have an XSD defining the message format put on the queue.

Answer (score 0):

There is one transport per endpoint.  As long as it is one way, you can expose your NSB endpoint as a web service.