# NServiceBus Pub/Sub using different Transports

Tags: nservicebus, publish-subscribe

Issue: Subscriber is not able to receive event from publisher because publisher and subscriber are using on different transports. Publisher and Subscriber are running on same server.

**Publisher** – NServiceBus 3.0 using MSMQ transport

**Subscriber** – NserviceBus 4.0 using MSSql transport

**ERROR**

```
Failed to subscribe to NServiceBus.Unicast.Queuing.QueueNotFoundException: Failed to send message to address: [publisher] ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name '......publisher'.
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler,TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, Run Behavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, BooleanasyncWrite)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
at NServiceBus.Transports.SQLServer.SqlServerMessageSender.ExecuteQuery(TransportMessage message, SqlCommand command) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\d4de8921a0aabf04\src\SqlServer\NServiceBus.SqlServer\SqlServerMessageSender.cs:line 150   at NServiceBus.Transports.SQLServer.SqlServerMessageSender.Send(TransportMessage message, Address address) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\d4de8921a0aabf04\src\SqlServer\NServiceBus.SqlServer\SqlServerMessageSender.cs:line 71
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at NServiceBus.Transports.SQLServer.SqlServerMessageSender.Send(TransportMessage message, Address address) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\d4de8921a0aabf04\src\SqlServer\NServiceBus.SqlServer\SqlServerMessageSender.cs:line 87   at NServiceBus.Unicast.Subscriptions.MessageDrivenSubscriptions.MessageDriven SubscriptionManager.SendMessage(Address publisherAddress, TransportMessage subscriptionMessage) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\d4de8921a0aabf04\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\Subscriptions\MessageDrivenSubscriptions\MessageDrivenSubscriptionManager.cs:line 149
at NServiceBus.Unicast.Subscriptions.MessageDrivenSubscriptions.MessageDrivenSubscriptionManager.SendSubscribeMessageWithRetries(Address destination, TransportMessage subscriptionMessage, String messageType, Int32 retriesCount) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\d4de8921a0aabf04\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\Subscriptions\MessageDrivenSubscriptions\MessageDrivenSubscriptionManager.cs:line 156 at publisher queue ...FeedAvailable, .....Messages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
```

Comment: Does this post help?:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729436/mixed-transports-in-nservicebus-4-0

Answer (score 1):

You need both sides to be using the same transport when doing pub/sub, request/response, etc.

Comment: Can I use MS-SQL and MSMQ transport on subscriber end because my subscriber is handing different command coming from MS-SQL transports? Yes can you please point me with some article or sample?